AWS SDK calls have higher latency in Kubernetes (EKS) compared to Elastic Container Service
I am working on migrating a Docker Spring Boot Reactive application from AWS ECS to AWS EKS.
In ECS, the task is allocated "cpu": "6144" & "memory": "16384".
In EKS, similar hard ware s allocated:
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 16Gi
    cpu: 6

When running the application in AWS EKS, I notice that all AWS SDK calls (DynamoDB Async updates, Firehose puts, etc) are taking 5-6x latency in Kubernetes EKS, compared to ECS.
I have ensured that the hardware configuration (EC2 host) is the same. I also confirmed that the available memory for the pod in EKS is same as the task in ECS.
How can I debug this? Is there a difference in the way http calls are made from Docker container in EKS and Docker container in ECS?
AWS SDK version used: 2.17.220
Update
I enabled AWS SDK Cloudwatch metrics on the app in both ECS and EKS. I notice that the following Cloudwatch metrics are very high in EKS (6x).

ConcurrencyAcquireDuration
ServiceCallDuration
ApiCallDuration

The AvailableConcurrency Cloudwatch metric was 0 in EKS, while it was always non-zero in ECS.
The other Cloudwatch metric values, like MaxConcurrency, are the same for both.
Could it be related to the "default number of I/O threads for a NettyNioAsyncHttpClient instance"?
How can I reduce the ConcurrencyAcquireDuration and increase the AvailableConcurrency?
Here is the code to create the AWS SDK DynamoDB client, where I am using the default NettyNioAsyncHttpClient:
MetricPublisher metricsPub = CloudWatchMetricPublisher.builder().build();
SdkAsyncHttpClient sdkAsyncHttpClient = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder().build();
DynamoDbAsyncClientBuilder builder = DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder();
DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient = builder
                                  .httpClient(sdkAsyncHttpClient)
                                  .overrideConfiguration(c -> c.addMetricPublisher(metricsPub)).region(Region.US_EAST_1).build();

